# Flutter type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' when getting from list

Tags: flutter, dart

When trying to compile my program, I get this error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HistoryPageState.builder.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:arkadas_testi/history.dart:54:38)
#1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
#2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1213:28)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1226:55)
#4      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2535:19)
...
====================================================================================================
```

This is my code:

```dart
var item = list[0];
int puan = int.parse(item["sonuc"]);
```

This is how `list` looks like: `[{arkadaşİsim: emir, kullaniciİsim: emir, sonuc: 76, yazi: Kesinlikle Arkadaş Ol}]`. `item["sonuc"]` is a String.

Even after converting "sonuc" to an int, the problem still occurs.

After looking through some questions with the similar answer, I still couldn't find the solution. How can I fix this problem? I can provide more code if the current information is not enough.

Comment: Could you add a little more code for us to have a minimun reproducible example?

Comment: Try removing the `int.parse()` part of the code. In maps if a value is a pure integer then it should return as one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you passing puan to some textfield and puan is an int now.
Anyways that's my guess as you haven’t explained the problem very well

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

```
void main() {
List list = [{'arkadaşİsim': 'emir', 'kullaniciİsim': 'emir', 'sonuc': 76, 'yazi': 'Kesinlikle Arkadaş Ol'}];
  double sum = 0;
  String string = 'String Sonuc:';
  sum = list[0]['sonuc'] + 10;
  //string += list[0]['sonuc']; => error, list[0]['sonuc'] => int
  string = string + list[0]['sonuc'].toString();
  print(sum);
  print(string);
  
}
```